# C++ map find most closest key

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map which maps longs as keys and Strings as Values. I need a method which takes a given long, searchs in the map and returns the value of the key which was as close as possible to the value.

Example:

```
std::map<std::long,string> mymap = {
            { 0,5, "Value1" },
            { 1,5, "Value2" },
            { 3, "Value3" } };

string getClosestValue(long randomnumber) {
 //dont know what to do
  return string
}
```

When I call the method like this: getClosestValue(0,9) I want the method to return "Value1" even though the key for "Value1" is 0,5. I want "Value1" instead of "Value2" because 0,9 is closer to 0,5 than 1,5.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what is 0,5 ? and 1,5 ?..

Comment: For that matter, what is `std::long`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do something like:

```
auto it = mymap.lower_bound(key)
```

using [`map`'s `lower_bound` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) to find the position into which `key` would have been inserted.

Now you need to compare `it == end(key)`. If it is `false`, you should record the key and value, increment `it`, and check again the key and value. Compare these two keys' distance to `key`, and return the value of the nearest one.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It might be added, that if `it == mymap.end()`, you need to return `(--it)->second`.

Comment: You also need to decrement `it` before you perform the comparison, not increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the library method [std::map::lower_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/).

It doesn't do exactly what you are looking for, but it gives you the position of an element very close to the one you are looking for.